# Term not found in Search but present in a term vector in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have term in my dataset which does not give any search results but is present in a document.

If I request a term vector:

```
GET index_5589b14f3004fb6be70e4724/document_set/382.txt/_termvector
{
  "fields" : ["plain_text", "pdf_text"],
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

The term vector has this word:

```
        ...
        "advis": {  //porter stemmed version of the word "advising"
           "doc_freq": 1,
           "ttf": 1,
           "term_freq": 1,
           "tokens": [
              {
                 "position": 81,
                 "start_offset": 412,
                 "end_offset": 420
              }
           ]
        },...
        "air": {
```

But when I search this word to retrieve all the documents where it has occurred I get zero hits:

```
GET index_5589b14f3004fb6be70e4724/document_set/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "advis",
      "fields": ["plain_text", "pdf_text"]
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: try querying *"advising"*  does that return values ?

Comment: Oh yes. It is returning!!
but I really have to search the terms that are returned by the term vector

Comment: i have updated the answer this is most probably because search term is being analyzed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the search term is getting analyzed most probably in the above example *advis* is being stemmed to *advi*.
You can explicitly specify *keyword* analyzer in the query and you should get the values

```
GET index_5589b14f3004fb6be70e4724/document_set/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "advis",
      "fields": ["plain_text", "pdf_text"],
      "analyzer" : "keyword"
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

Comment: This worked. You were right. The stemmed version of `advising` is `advis` but in search the word `advis` was being stemmed to `advi` which is not he root word of `advising`. Hence, I got zero hits.